# Unable to setContent in QDomDocument

Tags: c++, xml, qt, pyside

I have been trying to port a function written in Python/Pyside/Qt4.7.4 into C++, the sticking point is in setting the content for the QDomDocument.  In Python 2.6 I can do this:

```
doc = QtXml.QDomDocument("initData")
file = QtCore.QFile("initData.xml")
if not file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
   exit()
if not doc.setContent(file):
   file.close()
   exit()
```

And all is hunky dory (the file exists, can be read by the program, gets parsed, and the resulting DOM Document can be manipulated as I would expect), but in C++ (using Qt Creator 2.3.1, Qt 4.7.4, on OSX). If I try:

```
QFile *file = new QFile("/Users/UserName/Desktop/ProgramFolder/files/initData.xml");
file->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite|QIODevice::Text);
QDomDocument *doc = new QDomDocument;
doc->setContent(file);
```

I get:

```
Symbols not found
file not found
Collect2 - Id returned exit 1 status
file not found
```

When I remove lines three and four and replace them with an isOpen debugging statement I get confirmation that the file exists, and that Qt can read it.  Does anyone have any ideas that I can use to debug this?

Comment: The error output looks incomplete. Did you include QDomDocument? and link against QtXml? (QT += xml if you use quake).

Comment: I was missing the addition to the .pro.  Thanks!

Comment: Correcting myself: qmake, not quake, obviously ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QT += xml was missing from the QMake project file.